# Generate Download Content From Data Url with Javascript and HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, file, webrtc

I am developing a WebRTC application that transfers file over WebRTC data channel. After I successfully transfer the file as data url, I want to create a link says *"Click to download"* from that data url.

I have used HTML 5 `<a>` tag with `download` attribute to create that content. An examplary content as follows;

```
<a download="fileName" href="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAA...sc1BLBQYAAAAAGQAZAKoGAAD9eQAAAAA=">
```

It worked just fine for small contents that lesser than 16MB or so, but for bigger contents, it just didn't worked and nothing happened when you click.

Then I tried to open new page with data url as follows;

```
// event.message.content is base 64 data url
window.open(event.message.content,'Downloading');
```

This solution also worked for small contents, but failed to download big contents.

How could I download big content by using Javascript(pure javascript if possible) and HTML 5? <s>Is there any more efficent way than base64?</s> Thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe), now I know that base64 is not the efficent way. What would be the efficent way to do this?

Please feel free to ask for details if any missing.

Thanks,
Ugurcan

Edit: I've tried following code snippet, it worked for small content but not worked for bigger content too. It is probably same thing with the first one.

```
var save = document.createElement('a'),
    event;
save.href = message.content;
save.target = '_blank';
save.download = message.identifier;

event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('click', true, true);

save.dispatchEvent(event);
(window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
```

Comment: Browsers limit the size of URLs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: Thank you, now I know that I should use something other than data url.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/1400515) solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear – but _how_? As far as I can see, this answer is about _uploading_ data via a form, not downloading it to the client …?

Comment: I have added as answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Following code snippet derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/1400515) helped me to get Blob from base64 data uri.

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {
        type: mimeString
    });
}
```

Then I wrote this code snippet in order to download Blob content

```
var blob = dataURItoBlob(message.content);

var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var save = document.createElement('a'),
    event;
save.href = blobUrl;
save.download = message.identifier;

event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('click', true, true);

save.dispatchEvent(event);
(window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
```

Thanks for your kind help folks.